# Google Analytics Universal Custom Dimension not tracking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have set up a new site to use the new Google Analytics Universal tracking. The tracking code is installed correctly as pageview data etc is being recorded fine. I have set up a custom dimension but the data is not being recorded.

Here is my Google Analytics code:

```
<script>

    (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
        i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
        }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX', 'example.com');
    ga('set', 'dimension1', 'x');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

The custom dimension just isn't being tracked. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17310004/how-to-place-custom-variables-in-the-new-google-analytics-code

Comment: When you look into the request, ist there something like `cd1` with your parameter? If yes - you need to setup the custom dimension at your GA account https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en

Comment: @Jurik I see `cd3=the-value&cd4=other-value` in the request URL, but I have dimensions with indices 3 and 4 which are both active. But when I naviagate to Behavior -> Events -> Overview, click on a specific category and then try to add a Secondary dimension, there is nothing in it.

Comment: Oh, no, it finally appeared. It seems I had to wait some hours or maybe the whole day to be passed to see the results.